# Compare two tables and consider from specific table to insert

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

How do we take data from one table comparing with another?

I need to verify `tableA` and `tableB`: if the record exists in `tableB`, then consider `tableB`'s data - if not, use `tableA`'s data - and insert into `tableC`.

TableA

```
id    addressNumber  address2     unitno    zip
------------------------------------------------
1001    250-280      abc street             29383
1002    350-400      xyz street             29831
1003    475          hfg street             8474
```

tableB

```
id    addressNumber  address2     unitno    zip
------------------------------------------------
1001    250          abc street     22      29383
1001    260          abc street     24      29383
1001    280          abc street     23      29383
1002    350          xyz street     32      29831
1002    360          xyz street     34      29831
1002    390          xyz street     39      29831
```

Output into TableC:

```
id    addressNumber  address2     unitno    zip
------------------------------------------------
1001    250          abc street     22      29383
1001    260          abc street     24      29383
1001    280          abc street     23      29383
1002    350          xyz street     32      29831
1002    360          xyz street     34      29831
1002    390          xyz street     39      29831
1003    475          hfg street             8474
```

Here, id, addressnumber and unitno are primary keys

Comment: insert from a full outer join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select b.*
from b
union all
select a.*
from a
where not exists (select 1
                  from b
                  where b.id = a.id 
                 );
```